# Retina MacBook Pro Running 10.13.5 Can't Connect to Windows Fileshare Servers

Tags: network, smb

We have several Windows-based file shares and one computer can't connect to them. By default, he should be able to use `smb://server.name/share` from **Finder** > **Go** > **Connect to Server...** and then get prompted for his username and password, but instead he gets an error almost immediately that says:

> **There was a problem connecting to the server "server.name".**
>
> Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator.

Here's what we've tried so far in our troubleshooting:

- Tried restarting the computer
- Changed the server name to use the IP instead. No change in behavior
- Confirmed that the server name and IP can be pinged
- Tried using `cifs://` instead of `smb://`. No change in behavior
- Confirmed there aren't any saved credentials in **Keychain Access** that could be outdated
- Confirmed we get the same error when trying to connect to different servers with different shares and using different accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/262136/296316

Person had the Android development tools installed and so this was affecting their access to SMB shares. Removing the com.intel.kext.intelhaxm kext resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem on my computer a while ago.
I created a file `/etc/nsmb.conf` with the following contents:

```
[default]
signing_required=no
```

Be aware that you disable some security features with this procedure.
You can find more details in an [apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205926).

Comment: What a great resource to pass along! I was really hopeful this would solve the problem, but alas the issue persists.