# smb not working for me on 10.13.6 (dtruss inside)

Tags: finder, smb

my Finder is not able to connect to ANY smb-share. It doesn't matter, if the network-folder

- is on linux (SAMBA 4.1.17)
- is on OSX  (10.11.6)
- is on Windowsserver
- is public for everyone or in a ADS

It simply stops in the Finder with **"Couldn't connect"**

In the terminal you see the following

```
$ ping server
PING server (192.168.0.123): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.123: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.017 ms
^C
$ mount_smbfs  //johndoe@server/johndoe test
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No such file or directory
```

on a Debian-VM on the same macbookpro following command works perfectly

```
$ mount.cifs -o username=johndoe //server/johndoe test
```

In the logs is nothing, despite having kloglevel=15 in /etc/nsmb.conf and i have already tried 'configureLocalKDC' to reset the krb5.keytab

So i disabled System Integrity Protection and made a dtruss for the first command.

```
dtruss -cf mount_smbfs  //johndoe@server/johndoe test >& mount.log
```

mount.log has 2050 open-calls for the /dev/nsmb..

```
15734/0x1b2bd3:  open("/dev/nsmb\0", 0x2, 0x5F719DF8)            = -1 Err#2
15734/0x1b2bd3:  open("/dev/nsmb0\0", 0x2, 0xFFFFFFFFE84BC430)           = -1 Err#6
.... 2050times ...
15734/0x1b2bd3:  open("/dev/nsmb3fd\0", 0x2, 0xFFFFFFFFE84BC820)                 = -1 Err#2
15734/0x1b2bd3:  open("/dev/nsmb3fe\0", 0x2, 0xFFFFFFFFE84BC820)                 = -1 Err#2
15734/0x1b2bd3:  open("/dev/nsmb3ff\0", 0x2, 0xFFFFFFFFE84BC820)                 = -1 Err#2
```

/dev/nsmb0 exists .. the other ones not.
smbfs-module is loaded

```
$ kextstat | grep smb
  184    0 0xffffff7f8700b000 0x63000    0x63000    com.apple.filesystems.smbfs (3.2.3) 8BD2FFC5-F081-3B29-B2AB-BEF58E24BAAD
```

Has anyone hints, what I could do? I already tried mb_neg=smb3_only, protocol_vers_map and so on

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Oh my god..

it appears to be a problem with a 3rd party kext

see [Mac mini can't connect to my corporate SMB server. Was working some days ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257836/mac-mini-cant-connect-to-my-corporate-smb-server-was-working-some-days-ago/262136)

WTF apple. Fix your damn Error messages.